# How to Insert foreign key in other table using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using ***Django REST framework***, I'm stuck in Inserting foreign-key data into another table.
Please refer the scenario below:
As given below code, I want to insert data in `template` table and also insert foreign-key relationship into `template_owners` table using the single post request.
I tried few solutions but nothing worked as expected, Help is highly appreciated.

***Models.py:***

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

# Template model starts here.
class Template(models.Model):

    Yes = "Yes"
    No = 'No'

    STATUS = [
        (Yes, "Yes"),
        (No, "No"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        db_table = "template"
        ordering = ("date",)

    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    hypervisor = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False)
    download_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    metadata = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    command = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    size = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=True, default=0)
    is_default = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STATUS, default=Yes)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    owners = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Template [ uuid : {} ]" . format(self.uuid)

# Template model ends here.

# Template Owners model starts here.
class TemplateOwners(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "template_owners"
        ordering = ("date",)

    template_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Template, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="template_uuid")
    gid = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    uid = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    # def __init__(self):
    #   self.fields['name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please let us know what to call you!'}

    def __str__(self):
        return "Template Owner [ template_uuid : {} ]" . format(self.template_uuid)

# Template Owners model ends here.
```

***Serializers.py:***

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from template.models import Template, TemplateOwners

def trigger_validator(self, data):
    if data["name"] == "":
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"name": "Template name is required"})

    return data

class TemplateOwnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TemplateOwners  
        fields = ("gid", "uid", "date", "template_uuid")

class TemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owners = TemplateOwnerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Template
        fields = ("uuid", "name", "hypervisor", "download_url", "size", "date", "owners")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        owners_data = validated_data.pop('owners')
        template = Template.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for owner_data in owners_data:
            TemplateOwners.objects.create(template=template, **owner_data)
        return template
```

***Views.py:***

```
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from template.models import Template
from template.serializers import TemplateSerializer
from template.serializers import TemplateOwnerSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import generics

class TemplateList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Template.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TemplateSerializer

    def get(self, request, fromat=None):
        templates = Template.objects.all()
        serialized = TemplateSerializer(templates, many=True)
        return Response(serialized.data)

    def post(self, request, fromat=None):
        serializer = TemplateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            #tempowner = TemplateOwnerSerializer(data=request.data)
            #if tempowner.is_valid():
            #tempowner.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class TemplateModify(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = TemplateSerializer

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
                return Template.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Template.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, fromat=None):
        template = self.get_object(pk)
        serialized = TemplateSerializer(template)
        return Response(serialized.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, fromat=None):
        template = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = TemplateSerializer(template, data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        template = self.get_object(pk)
        template.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

There are few questions related to Foreignkey in Django Rest Framework but none of the are concerned about data insertion they mainly focus on data fetching, So please go through whole scenario before marking duplicate.

Comment: post the stacktrace and also which field you are trying to insert?

Comment: @Exprator, I want to insert uuid, gid, uid, date in template_owners table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have few problems with the serializer and also the creation, so change them accordingly

```
class TemplateOwnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TemplateOwners  
        fields = ("gid", "uid", "date")

class TemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owners_data = TemplateOwnerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Template
        fields = ("uuid", "name", "hypervisor", "download_url", "size", "date", "owners_data")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        owners_data = validated_data.pop('owners_data')
        template = Template.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for owner_data in owners_data:
            TemplateOwners.objects.create(template_uuid=template, **owner_data)
        return template
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it helped me also but having one question: How would I do the same for one more table. I mean I need to insert the same foreign-key and some other data into some another table. I did it in same way but it only inserts data in first table not in second table. Awaiting for your response.